# How to select common items

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Work on C# linq.I have a **list to list**.From this list I want to get  the common items

```
List<SQLFrameWorkTableEntity> oParent = new List<SQLFrameWorkTableEntity>();

            List<List<SQLFrameWorkTableEntity>> oChild = new List<List<SQLFrameWorkTableEntity>>();
            oListParentTable = oList.Where(p => p.Parent == true).ToList();
            foreach (SQLFrameWorkEntity item in oListParentTable)
            {           

                oChild.Add(GetTableSchemaList(item, oParent));
            }
```

[image]
Above picture describe how my oChild is.
Now this **oChild** is the list of list **SQLFrameWorkTableEntity**.I want to get the common items from the **oChild**.How to get it?If have any query plz ask.Thanks in advance

After replace List to List> ,I write the bellow linq syntax

```
 var r=oChild.Select(p => p.Select(x => p.Any(y => y.ColumnName == x.ColumnName))).ToList();
```

Here, in r  i get all list item are true,that means i fail to compare with list to list.Help me to correction this syntax.Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the common items from the `oChild`"? And why is `oChild` not strongly typed as List<List<SQLFrameWorkTableEntity>>` or something similar? It's not really clear what you mean.

Comment: thanks jon skeet ,i don't know this process List<List<SQLFrameWorkTableEntity>>.Thanks ,I change my syntax .Now will you plz tell me how to get the common items from the list of list.thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to find the items that occur in *all* lists produced by `GetTableSchemaList(item, oParent)`? Let's assume yes.

First add `Distinct()` (if one list is not distinct yet):

```
oChild.Add(GetTableSchemaList(item, oParent).Distinct());
```

Then after the `foreach` do:

```
var count = oListParentTable.Count;
var r = oChild.SelectMany(i => i).GroupBy(i => i)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == count).SelectMany(i => i).Distinct();
```

The idea is that "common items" should occur exactly, say, 4 times in the flattened list of lists (SelectMany) when the number of distinct lists in oChild is 4.

Comment: excellent job ,thanks GertArnold.Hai!it's confuse me.I try to understand how it's work.Excellent .Thanks again.Will you plz show me some guideline to understand this kind of complex query.

Comment: Thanks! A guideline: training! What I did when LINQ was introduced is take the documentation on [IEnmerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) and do some exercises with each and every extension method.

Comment: After use your syntax i get common it's but common items are duplicate .i need unique list.will you plz extension your syntax.

Comment: You probably should do something like `GroupBy(i => i.ColumnName)`. So you group by ColumnName, which is a property that identifies a `SQLFrameWorkTableEntity`.

Comment: GertArnold thanks for reply.i already write syntax as              oCommonList = oChild.SelectMany(i => i).GroupBy(i => i.ColumnName)
                .Where(g => g.Count() > 1).SelectMany(i => i).Distinct().ToList();

Comment: This syntax gives me common duplicate item.Suppose list one and list two have common item=A.above syntax show me common A ,A on my list,but i want just one item show in list Just A

Comment: The problem is that your `A` objects are not the same instance, so Distinct() does not work. Use [this overlaod of Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx). Make an IEqualityComparer that says that objects with the same ColumnName are equal.